# Perturbation Theory in Orbital Interactions in Chemistry

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In the entire book, perturbation theory is used as a qualitative tool to rationalise some chemical phenomena. The authors write that

$$\psi_i = \sum_\mu{T_{ji}\psi_j^\circ}\tag{1}$$

The proof of the derivation for $T_{ji}$ involves the following statement:

$$T_{ji} = \left(\mathbf{C}_j^\circ\right)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{S}^\circ\mathbf{C}_i \tag{2}$$

where

$$\left(\mathbf{C}_j^\circ\right)^\mathrm{T} = \left(C_{1j}^\circ \quad C_{2j}^\circ \quad \cdots \quad C_{mj}^\circ\right)\tag{3}$$

(indexing the coefficients for the *j*th unperturbed MO), and

$$
\mathbf{C}_i =
\begin{pmatrix}
C_{1i} \\
C_{2i} \\
\vdots \\
C_{mi} 
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{4}
$$

(indexing the coefficients for the $i$th perturbed MO); $\mathbf{S},$ the overlap matrix, is defined as usual.

I'm not quite sure how the aforementioned statement is obtained. Could someone please walk me through how

$$T_{ji} = \sum\sum C_{nj}^\circ S_{nm}C_{mi}?$$

Source: Orbital Interactions in Chemistry, 2nd edition, page 794-802

Comment: Please utilize MathJax for typesetting math and chemical formulas whenever possible: this makes them searchable and reduces traffic (especially if images are large). Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Also, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This equation (as written) is wrong; it's not actually in the book. The (correct) formula is inversely proportionate to $E_j^{(0)} - E_i^{(0)}$. It is a standard result in quantum mechanics and I suggest looking in a QM textbook of choice. Or the Internet. There are lots of good websites with the full derivation - search "perturbation theory".

Comment: Also, please add a complete reference for the textbook you are quoting from, and format quoted portions of the text as such with `>`.

Comment: @orthocresol it's in Appendix 1, and I've reflected that in an edit.

Comment: Ah, ok, I take that back then, sorry. It is confusing because in the actual text they have $t_{ji}$ which has a different meaning...

Comment: @orthocresol it's actually the same meaning as in the text; the Appendix simply tries to derive the expressions for intermolecular, electronegativity and geometrical perturbation from first principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than focusing on the individual matrix entries, it may be more intuitive to look at the matrix $\mathbf{T}$ formed by putting together all entries $T_{ij}$. In this case, $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{S}^0\mathbf{C}$, where $\mathbf{C}$ is the coefficient matrix with column $k$ denoting how atomic orbitals mix together into molecular orbital $k$.

Now the point is that molecular orbitals, or the columns of $\mathbf{C}$, are orthonormal and are eigenfunctions of $H_{eff}$ (see page 34). This orthonormality makes sense if you think of the Hamiltonian matrix, which is certainly self-adjoint, and solving the eigenproblem is equivalent to diagonalizing the matrix with an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Hence, $\mathbf{C}$ is unitary, and $\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{S}^0\mathbf{C}$ can be simply seen as a change-of-basis transformation done on the overlap matrix from atomic basis to the molecular orbital basis.

I hope this rather mathematical perspective may be of help to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It look like the expression is just the equivalent way of expression the matrix product. I've attached two pictures that might help.[image: maytrix-pic2]

[image: matrix pic1]

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question; I don't understand the rationalise behind the matrix expression itself, and had simply restated it in terms of the double summation. Thanks for the help, though!